# Proper way to reduce number of DLL files in your application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ilmerge

I am looking for a way to "reduce" the number of DLL files in my ASP.NET application.
At the moment I have a solution with large amount of projects with lots of cross reference DLLs being copied around.

I have been looking into iLMerge.

I was thinking of creating a batch in each project (as a post build event) that would merge assemblies based on their file name / or some sort of auto grouping (just to avoid listing them all, since there is a whole bunch of them).

Sort of:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /out:My.Types.dll My.Types.*.dll

that would work same as listing all of the DLL files:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /out:My.Types.dll My.Types.A.dll My.Types.B.dll My.Types.C.dll My.Types.D.dll ...

Can someone help me out here... is iLMerge the right tool for me?

Comment: While this might work, this might bring more problems than it solves. And after all - is there a problem to solve at all? Why number of dlls bothers you?

Comment: When deploying into a farm based environment ... the large amount of small files combined with slow HDD takes too much time. Its only one step of speeding up the deployment.

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but you might find this interesting: http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-merge-assemblies-into-wpf-application and this http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2013/01/want-to-ilmerge-but-you-building-wpf.html (I use ILMerge myself and am satisfied, but am not using ASP or XAML.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if iLMerge is the correct tool, but this sounds like the exact problem we ran into a few years back in where our projects needed hundreds of dll references from our core project as this project was multiple projects in one solution as the following structure

- solution "main"
- project "main.user.businesslogic"
- project "main.user.dataaccess"
- project "main.user.model"

And we did the same for all other entity's in the same structure . When we build the solution it's hundreds of dll's
And this wastes time as you would know.

We decided to drop the multiple projects and just have one 
Where our structure remained sort of the same the projects just became folders in one project, in the end this was a tedious move and very time consuming but it's a lot more manageable now than what it was.

Our structure looks a bit more like the following now

- solution "main"
- project "main.core"
- folder "main.core.businesslogic"
- folder "main.core.dataaccess"
- folder "main.core.model"

and inside the folders are our various classes

When we build its one dll and easy to reference in out various projects

Hope this helps and is applicable to the question you asked